# SAP HANA - show results in same pane

Tags: hana, hana-studio

Does anyone know how to get HANA Studio to show the results at the bottom of the pane instead of as a separate tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do that. SAP HANA Studio always creates a tab for the display of result set(s). 
But since HANA accepts general JDCB connections, you could use tools like "SQuirreL" or "DB Beaver" to develop your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I use SAP HANA IDE for SQL development and getting the results at the bottom of the pane instead of a separate tab in HANA Studio.

[image]